# What is the meaning of this C++ macro?

Tags: c++, macros, concatenation, c-preprocessor

I can't figure out what this macro means:

```
#define DECLARE_HANDLE(n) typedef struct n##__{int i;}*n

DECLARE_HANDLE(HWND);
```

I have learned from the **C** program that:

> "##"  means connect  the parameter.

so the macro equals:

```
typedef struct HWND__{int i;}*HWND
```

Is this right?

If it is right, what is the meaning of that sentence?

==================

Code from a game Bombermaaan (for Windows and Linux), 
link http://sourceforge.net/p/bombermaaan/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/Bombermaaan/winreplace.h, 
line No 90.

Comment: what does this mean? 
#define INVALID_SOCKET (SOCKET)(~0)

Comment: `~` is the *logical not* operator, which in this case will revert all the bits of the number in which you put 0 in. `char sock = INVALID_SOCKET;` will be 0xFF, `int sock = INVALID_SOCKET` will be 0xFFFFFFFF.

Comment: thanks @Sean for ask the question, a good question.  and thanks Xgbi for your very detail answer.

Comment: It means, in part, that somebody likes to create invalid identifiers. Names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved to the implementation and should not be used in any other code.

Comment: @xgbi: `~` will *invert*, not revert, the bits.

Comment: @PeteBecker, The `HWND__` part I can understand. The Windows API is pretty much meant to be used with MSVC (and yes, I use it with GCC daily), and Microsoft *is* an implementer. I like to think of it as implementation code.

Comment: @xgbi, I would argue that `!` is the logical not operator. `~` is better off the bitwise not operator.

Comment: @chris - those names are reserved to the **implementation**, not to the **implementor**. And the implementation is the compiler and standard library; the language definition does not extend this allowance to whatever else the implementor happens to want to throw into the box. Playing fast and loose with reserved identifiers makes it harder for other implementations to work with such non-conforming headers. Unfortunately, most OS vendors think they are part of the implementation...

Comment: @PeteBecker, Yeah, it's a real shame, I know, but I doubt it's going to change any time soon. There are actual libraries that use reserved identifiers as well, which also sucks.

Comment: @KeithThompson : yeah well, I'm not english, excuse the wording :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The main purpose of this construct is to prevent the misuse of handles. If all handles are simply `void *` or `int` or `long long` or some other basic type, there is nothing to prevent you from using one instead of another. A pointer to a `struct HWND__` and pointer to `struct HBITMAP__` isn't the same thing, so if you have a the following code:

```
HWND hwnd;
HBITMAP hbmp;

hbmp = GetBitmap(...);
hwnd = hbmp;    // gives compiler error.
```

It's a fairly classic technique to ensure that you get unique types for something that the API supplier don't want to provide the true declaration for. Although I'm not entirely sure why they even need a proper struct declaration, you could probably get away with:

```
#define DECLARE_HANDLE(n) struct n ## __; struct n ## __ *n;
```

That will also ensure that any dereferece HWND won't be possible, since the compiler will object to "use of incomplete type".

Comment: It's a *little* bit annoying if you want to use a smart pointer to clean it up, though, and I'm not sure if holding a `decltype(*std::declval<HWND>()>)` is safe (I was going to ask about that sometime). Doing that makes for a nice RAII `Handle` class. Keep in mind `STRICT` plays a part here as well.

Comment: @Chris: Probably a better idea to wrap the whole HWND handling into a class that creates the window object, handles it, and then on destruction closes it.

Comment: Well, windows are a little finicky (you don't want to acquire someone else's window and have it do that for you), `HWND` is just the first handle that comes to my mind. My plan with this was to make a pure `Handle` class for holding the handle and cleaning up with the user-supplied function and to have actual classes that represent these objects and can use the `Handle` class to manage the resource more easily. In an ideal world, the user wouldn't have to know the `Handle` class exists.

Comment: @chris: I guess you could do something like that with templates, and just write a "closing function" for the types that you know what to close them with, and let the user supply one if there are multiple choices.

Comment: Definitely, I've already done that to test it out. The smart pointer uses that trick for what to point to and `Handle<HDESK>` would be one example of use, with lambdas being amazing for specifying cleanup code (I guess an alteration for `T(WINAPI *)(HandleType)` could be useful if no error checking is done). I [asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16676701/is-relying-on-the-type-of-a-windows-handle-being-a-pointer-ok) about the whole assuming it's a pointer thing, though.

Answer (score 6):

Your assumption is correct.

You can check this with the following simple test code.

```
DECLARE_HANDLE(HWND);
struct HWND__ s;
HWND p = (HWND) malloc(sizeof(struct HWND__));
s.i = 20;
p->i = 100;
cout << "i valueis " << s.i<<" and " << p->i <<endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

Exactly.

This is used to declare an opaque pointer to a structure that is unknown to you.

I don't know why they didn't simply declare it as a

```
typedef void* HWND;
```

<s>Probably for alignment issues, since structures can be aligned but not basic types</s>.
As mentioned above, declaring the type as a structure permits some compile-time type checking.
Clever!

Comment: It is mainly so that you use HWND where you want HWND, and HBITMAP where you want HBITMAP, etc. If they are just `void *`, you can do `HWND h = CreateBitmap(...);`.

Comment: As Mats mentioned, void* doesn't allow typechecking (diffrent handle types can be mixed). However, I don't understand why not simply #define DECLARE_HANDLE(n) typedef struct n##__ *n; (without actual struct definition) that would provide true opacity and prevent from something like ++myhandle.

Comment: in non-STRICT builds, I believe it is `typedef`ed to void *. See  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383681%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

`DECLARE_HANDLE(HWND);` indeed expands to

```
typedef struct HWND__{int i;}*HWND;
```

Now, you're asking what it means? Just split the typedef into two steps:

```
struct HWND__
{
    int i;
};

typedef HWND__* HWND;  // C++ only; for both C++ and C: typedef struct HWND__* HWND;
```

Thus, it defines a struct `HWND__` containing an `int` (named `i`) and declares a type alias `HWND` as *pointer to `HWND__`*.

Answer (score 0):

It defines a `HWND` as a pointer to `struct HWND__` that contains `int i`.

So, now you can use in the code the type `HWND`.

Comment: thank's for your kindness for explanation the code's meaning.